# How should I tag Ki Techniques in Anima: Beyond Fantasy?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, I ran into a question about the interaction of two damage modifiers that you can put on a technique.  The problem is, I don't know how to tag the entire Ki system, and I don't want to go inventing tags whole cloth if, for example, [spellcasting] will do from a mechanical standpoint.

How should I tag Ki Technique questions?

Comment: I don't know the system you are using. But in general it is better to use the actual name of the feature/system rather than abstracting it to spellcasting when it isn't really appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest keep things simple and tag them by what the game calls them. If the game calls them Ki Techniques, tag them [ki-techniques]. This would also be the words that Anima players are looking for, I imagine.

If later we discover that's causing problems we can revise or merge the tag as necessary.

Comment: Okay then.  I'll do that.